# AngularJS: Why won't ng-click set a variable as a value obtained from ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to give an app the ability to set the font for portion of text based on a list of fonts from Google Fonts.

Here's what I have:

```
<ul ng-init='headerFont="mono"'>
  <li ng-repeat='font in fonts' style='font-family: {{font}};' ng-click='headerFont = font'>{{font}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and then later on:

```
<h1 style='font-family: {{headerFont}};'>Header</h1>
```

and in the controller in my js file:

```
$scope.fonts = [...an array of font names...]
```

Originally, instead of `ng-repeat` on `<li>`, I was using:

```
<select ng-model='headerFont' style='font-family: {{headerFont}};'>
  <option ng-repeat='font in fonts' style='font-family:{{font}};'>{{font}}
  </option>
</select>
```

And that worked exactly like I wanted it to. But I wanted to try using a scrollable list instead of a drop-down menu because the `<select>` menu on mobile browsers doesn't support changing fonts of individual options, and it's important to me for the fonts to be able to be previewed before choosing. I figured I could just use `ng-click` to set the value of `headerFont`, but it doesn't do anything (no errors show up in the console or anything. Just nothing happens.) Does anyone know why?

Comment: It would be much easier if you could provide a jsFiddle or plunkr or something with your question. Anyway I think you can use `ng-style` directive and don't use statements in your declarative code (HTML), instead make that one line of code a method in your controller, it would be much easier to debug or follow later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that ngRepeat creates child scope for each iteration, so ngClick actually changes local child `headerFont` variable.

One possible solution is to explicitly refer parent scope:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.controller('demoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.fonts = ['Arial', 'Times New Roman', 'Verdana', 'mono'];
})
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demoController">
    <h1 style='font-family: {{headerFont}};'>Header</h1>

    <ul ng-init='headerFont="mono"'>
        <li ng-repeat='font in fonts' style='font-family: {{font}};' ng-click='$parent.headerFont = font'>{{font}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Each `ng-repeat` creates a new scope. The `ng-click` changes the `headerFont` in its own scope, without touching the `headerFont` on the top level.

You can create dictionary at the top level to prevent the child scope from kicking in:

```
<ul ng-init="top = {'headerFont':'mono'}">
 <li ng-repeat='font in fonts' 
     style='font-family: {{font}};' 
     ng-click='top.headerFont = font'>
   {{font}} / {{top.headerFont}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/77zesZsBgYpZUDWciY18?p=preview

Comment: Is there another way for me to set top level values inside of the repeat scope?

Comment: @Nathan dsfq provided an answer which handles one level of inheritance. I have updated the answer which could handle several level of inheritance.

Comment: Agree, this dot-fix is more flexible in case of nested scopes, like includes, ngIf, etc.